# base64 encode binary string returns different values in NodeJS and Python

Tags: python, node.js, encryption, encoding, base64

I am trying to base64 encode a binary string in NodeJS and python and I'm getting 2 different values.

Note that the value is `i` is 16 random bytes generated in python using `os.urandom(16)`

NodeJS

```js
> var i = '>e\x93\x10\xabK\xbe\xfeX\x97\x9a$\r\xef\x8f3';
> var s = new Buffer(i).toString('base64');
> console.log(s);
PmXCkxDCq0vCvsO+WMKXwpokDcOvwo8z
```

Python

```py
>>> import base64
>>> i = '>e\x93\x10\xabK\xbe\xfeX\x97\x9a$\r\xef\x8f3'
>>> s = base64.b64encode(i)
>>> print s
PmWTEKtLvv5Yl5okDe+PMw==
```

Am I doing something wrong? It does work for regular string such as my name.

NodeJS

```js
> var s = new Buffer('travis').toString('base64');
undefined
> console.log(s);
dHJhdmlz
```

Python

```py
>>> s = base64.b64encode('travis')
>>> print s
dHJhdmlz
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NodeJS is encoding the *UTF-8* representation of the string. Python is encoding the byte string.

In Python, you'd have to do:

```py
>>> i = u'>e\x93\x10\xabK\xbe\xfeX\x97\x9a$\r\xef\x8f3'
>>> i.encode('utf8').encode('base64')
'PmXCkxDCq0vCvsO+WMKXwpokDcOvwo8z\n'
```

to get the same output.

You created the buffer using a default encoding, which means it interpreted `i` as UTF-8 to begin with. You need to tell `Buffer` to treat `i` as binary instead:

```js
> var i = '>e\x93\x10\xabK\xbe\xfeX\x97\x9a$\r\xef\x8f3';
> var s = new Buffer(i, 'binary').toString('base64');
> s
'PmWTEKtLvv5Yl5okDe+PMw=='
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems I was experiencing this because I was hardcoding the value of i for testing. But generating it properly works.

Comment: Thanks! I spent two days to find the issue of my hash function, I never thought about different result between nodejs and other languages like python/php/perl... We are getting the same with hash `crypto.createHash("sha1").update(data, "binary")`, I don't understand why we don't have warning in the documentation^^".